# Is it possible to persist connection between page loads using XMPP, Strophe.js & Websockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket, xmpp, chat, strophe

I'm building a chat application using `strophe`.js (websockets) and would like to avoid having to reconnect/re-auth to the server on page reload/redirect (served by Django.)

My understanding is that:

- global js scope is destroyed on every page load
- websocket connection is terminated on unload

Alternatives are:

- single page (which I would like to avoid because of lack of search engine page indexing)

Note: I am aware of using bosh and attaching on page reloads/redirects.

Comment: If you are aware of attaching, can you improve your question to say what about that does not solve your problem?